# Interconnected technique for web, mobile and desktop

Tags: php, api, mobile, web, applications

I am planning to do the university project with the Desktop application + web application + mobile application, I have planned to use languages for these 3 as below:

- Desktop application: Java SE
- Web application: PHP
- Mobile application: flutter with Dart
- Database: Mysql

Now I have a problem with how to connect these 3 with the same database.

for example:
Desktop application can connect without any issue because both are in the same network. problem is how to connect mobile and web application with a local database.

Kindly advise me on how to manage that situation.

Thank you!!

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

## You Require an API.

This is a server at a well know ip/domain name that the mobile/web app/desktop app can contact via a network protocol such as HTTPS to retrieve data, and submit updates/requests.

You may also need to create a task manager for performing offline processing as requested/needed by the API. This isn't for quick tasks such as saving data to the db, but more complex/lengthy processing that would easily cause the http worker/client/human to timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about developing a [PWA (Progressive Web App)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps) instead? I believe it could be a Jack-of-all-trades.

A PWA allows good usage regardless of the device -- desktop, mobile, web, etc. It can be downloaded for offline usage and therefore proves itself to be very reliable and flexible.

Moreover, it'd be only one application developed which could then be used everywhere basically. So you could use one set of languages/tech stack, and have it be used in all those environments you mentioned.

Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Introduction#Advantages_of_web_applications) for more info & general benefits of the PWA approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for the valuable idea